# iOS UISearchController width Not equal screen,Right less than screen

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller

```
- (UISearchController *)searchController {
    if (_searchController == nil) {
        _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];

        _searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;

        _searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = YES;

        _searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES;

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _searchController.searchBar;
    }
    return _searchController;
}
```

Comment: Hi! It's not clear what your asking. Can you tell us what's the desired behaviour and what are you getting? You might consider looking here to find out how to make good question so that others can answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use UITableViewController, instead use UIViewController subclass. Arrange Searchbar and Tableview. Dont put Search bar in tableview header.

Note: UITableViewController with Indexed search always gives you extra space on right side.

Comment: thank you ; My VC is super from UITableViewController; is because "- (NSArray<NSString *> *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView" ;  This is not a error.